# How to bind Tooltip in code behind?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, binding

I have a class (which will serve as a base class for my user controls) that I want to be able to set the binding of the tooltip through the code behind. I can't seem to figure out quite how to make it work right. I want to set the binding to a property called "ToolTipText" by calling a function "SetToolTip" from the constructor.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Public MyBaseClass
Inherits UserControl
Private _ToolTipText As String = "This is the default text!!"
Public Property ToolTipText As String
    Get
        Return _ToolTipText
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _ToolTipText = value

    End Set
End Property

Private Sub SetToolTip()
    Me.ToolTip = New ToolTip With {.MinHeight = 30, .MinWidth = 150, .FontSize = 16, .Foreground = Brushes.White}

    Dim ToolTipBinding As Binding = New Binding
    ToolTipBinding.Source = Me
    ToolTipBinding.Path = New PropertyPath("ToolTipText")
    ToolTipBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
    ToolTipBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged

    BindingOperations.SetBinding(Me.ToolTip, ToolTipService.ToolTipProperty, ToolTipBinding)
End Sub

Public Sub New()
    SetToolTip()
End Sub
End Class
```

However when I mouseover, I only get an empty tooltip (no text). I use snoop (if anyone else is familiar with that tool), and it doesn't list any bindings for my class' tooltip property. But the weird part is that if I delve into the tooltip property, I shows that the tooltip has it's own tooltip property which is set to the correct text. It seems I somehow need to bind to the tooltip's content and not it's own tooltip property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just figured it out. The line which sets the binding should read:

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(Me.ToolTip, ContentControl.ContentProperty, ToolTipBinding)
```

I's kind of strange to think, but before I was setting the tooltip's tooltip.